# Как в QML вывести видео в кнопке круглой формы

Tags: qt, qml

У меня есть кастомная кнопка круглой формы которую мне нужно заполнить повторяющимся видео, которое должно повторять форму кнопки.
C выводом видео внутри кнопки проблем нет, главная проблема в том как придать видео форму круга.
Код того что есть сейчас:

```
TButtonDoubleCircle
        {
             id: button
             anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
             anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
             visible: true
             Video {
                 id: video
                 source: "video.mp4"
                 autoPlay: true
                 anchors.fill: parent
                 visible: true
                MouseArea {
                     anchors.fill: parent
                     onClicked: {
                         video.play()
                     }
                 }
                onPositionChanged:
                {
                    if (video.position > 9500)
                    {
                        video.seek(video.position - 10000);
                        video.play()
                    }
                }
                onStopped: video.play()
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, после некоторых експериментов мне удалось это сделать при помощи масок

```
TButtonDoubleCircle
{
     id: button
     anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
     anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
     visible: true
             Image {
                 id: mask
                 anchors.centerIn: button
                 fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                 width: 400
                 height: 400
                 source: "qrc:/images/circle.png"
                 visible: false
             }
Video {
         id: video
         anchors.centerIn: button
         width: 400
         height: 300
         fillMode: VideoOutput.PreserveAspectCrop
         notifyInterval: 100
         source: "/dump.mp4"
         visible: true
         loops: Animation.Infinite
        MouseArea {
             anchors.fill: parent
             onClicked: {
                 video.play()
             }
         }
        onPositionChanged:
        {
            if (video.position > 9800)
            {
                video.seek(video.position - 10000);
                video.play()
            }
        }
        onStopped: video.play()
     }
     TRectangle{
         anchors.centerIn: button
         opacity: 0
         width: button.width - button.width/5
         height: button.width - button.width/5
     }
 OpacityMask{
     anchors.centerIn: button
     cached: true
     width: button.width - button.width/5
     height: button.width - button.width/5
     source: video
     maskSource: mask
 }
 onClicked: video.play()
}
```